# How to style adornment in Material UI TextField?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add just the default 14px padding-left set by `startAdornment` and want to make it so the adornment takes up half of the `TextField` instead. I can't seem to figure out how to style the `startAdornment` in general.

I tried style the div itself, this works but there is still an underlying 14px padding left. I tried styling the `InputAdornment` itself but it seems to have no effect.

```
InputProps={
    this.state.didChange[rowIndex] ? {
        startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment
                position="start"
                component="div"
                style={{paddingLeft: '-14px'}}
                disablePointerEvents>
                <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#D3D4D0', marginLeft: '-14px', padding: "10px 13px", width: "26px", color: '#a1a39b' }}>
                    {prevVals[rowIndex]}
                </div>
            </InputAdornment>
        )
    } : null} />
```

This is the result of my current code:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

You can ignore the border color difference that doesn't matter I can change that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) demonstrating the current state. That would give others a much faster starting point for experimenting with and verifying potential solutions.

Comment: I figured it out. So the position="start" kept adding another margin right 8px. O.o

Answer (score 20):

there are `adornedStart` and `adornedEnd` classes in [FilledInput](https://material-ui.com/api/filled-input/) and [OutlinedInput](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/) classes.so you can either use them or use [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) 
 `InputProps` dependig on what variant you use.

```
 <TextField
           name={'text'}
           variant="outlined"
           InputProps={{
               endAdornment:
               <IconButton onClick={()=>0}>x</IconButton>,
               classes: {
                          adornedEnd: classes.adornedEnd
                         }
               }}
           />
```

here is [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-adornment-example-1j79z)

Comment: Where does "classes" come from?

Comment: @Xeoncross either use makeStyles()
https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api
or withStyles
https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ppv2w?file=/demo.js

Comment: This works, but throws an error for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the background color of the `InputAdornment` by removing the padding left of the `OutlinedInput` and set a matching padding in your adornment (based on the padding of the input [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js#L64));

```
import MuiTextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const TextField = styled(MuiTextField)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
    paddingLeft: 0,
  },
  '& .MuiInputAdornment-root': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.divider,
    padding: '28px 14px',
    borderTopLeftRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius + 'px',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius + 'px',
  },
}));
```

```
<TextField
  placeholder="Password"
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <Visibility />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]