# React js material-ui textfield endAdornment background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I followed the instructions found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61708197/8024296

But the example code doesn't seem to work anymore.

How can I do such a thing, but without that margin on the right is that it follows the rounded trend of the input field.

[image]

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
<TextField
          label="Name File"
          id="outlined-start-adornment"
          className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">.docx</InputAdornment>,
            classes: {
              adornedEnd: classes.adornedEnd
            }
          }}
          variant="outlined"
        />
```

[image]

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-iwrs5?file=/demo.js)

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected to achieve the desired style I suggest adding this line of code:

background: 'linear-gradient(-90deg, #CCC 30%, #FFF 30%)'

instead of backgroundColor: "#ccc".

Happy coding!

Comment: The code seems to work but there is a problem,
if I take this out: `className = {clsx (classes.margin, classes.textField)}`
I need all fields to be fullWidth and the same size, I get this in production:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZhwd.png

A similar thing can also be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-iwrs5?file=/demo.js

Comment: So you want all of the fields to have this grey block?

Comment: I have tried to recreate the problem with the code sandbox you gave, but I could not.

Comment: There is the code sandbox [https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-drh08?file=/demo.js:2595-2597](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-drh08?file=/demo.js:2595-2597)

Answer (score 0):

you were so close just addjust your code to be like this

```
adornedEnd: {
    backgroundColor: "#ccc",
    height: "2.4rem",
    maxHeight: "3rem",
  }
```

And modify InputProps as follow:

```
InputProps={{endAdornment: <InputAdornment className={clsx(classes.adornedEnd)} position="end">.docx</InputAdornment>,
style: {
   paddingRight: "0"
}}}
```

this will solve the problem
a working example on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/mustafa-agha/pen/xxqNzZV)
a working example on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ppv2w?file=/index.js:1-149)

> (be careful you can edit it)